# Can I run python script with test using k6 tool?

Tags: python, load-testing, k6, entity-framework-6.4

I have a script in python with 1 test in it.
The test calls other functions from different class in the project which generate differeydata each time to be send through the post request in the test.
I want to run this test using the k6 tool, for 5 users for example.
Is it possible? Or only Javascript

Comment: instead of k6 you can you locust load testing library

Answer (score 1):

As of [current version 0.42.0](https://github.com/grafana/k6/releases/tag/v0.42.0) it doesn't seem to be possible. If your machine has an [SSH server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers) running you can go for [xk6-ssh](https://github.com/grafana/xk6-ssh) extension to connect to the machine where your python script lives and run it.

Alternatively you can come up with your own k6 extension allowing execution of local commands.

However I don't think it's a viable approach because you're unlikely to get good results and metrics.

Maybe it worth considering migrating to [Locust](https://locust.io/) tool which is Python-based so you can write a [Locustfile](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html) around your Python script logic and it will be executed with the given number of virtual users.

Check out [What Is Locust Load Testing?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-load-testing) for more information if needed.